# Record video from custom camera app to internal memory

Tags: android, video, save, gallery, media

Okay, I've exhausted all links and can't seem to find the answer.

I have followed [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to creating a video camera app and I can't seem to get the file to save.

In the tutorial it talks about saving to external memory, the phone I am developing on is a Google Nexus 4 and doesn't have external memory! So I am trying to save to internal memory but I have no idea how to do this with video. I also read the [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) guide too but again, I am finding this of little use...

Ideally, I would like to do this so that the recorded video is displayed in the Gallery so any assistance/pointing in the right direction would be great! My current saving methods looks like the following which replicates that in the android tutorial. I know it's here the code needs to be edited but I'm not sure what too.

```
/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
// To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
// using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
// This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
// between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

// Create the storage directory if it does not exist
if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
    if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
        return null;
    }
}

// Create a media file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
} else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
} else {
    return null;
}

return mediaFile;
}
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but I've spent six hours looking at this now trying different things. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the tutorial it talks about saving to external memory

It is called "external storage". You can tell that by [reading](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

> the phone I am developing on is a Google Nexus 4 and doesn't have external memory

[Yes, it does](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer.
>
> It's possible that a device using a partition of the internal storage for the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. In this case, the SD card is not part of the external storage and your app cannot access it (the extra storage is intended only for user-provided media that the system scans).

The tutorial's code shows requesting the video to be saved to external storage. Your device has external storage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I feel a tad stupid right now but I saw the word external and just assumed this meant external to the device i.e.SD card. After re-reading it makes much better sense. :)

Comment: @user99903: Yes, their choice of names leaves something to be desired.